# виртуальный синтезатор под линукс?

Tags: linux, поиск-программ

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, виртуальный синтезатор под линукс, чтобы можно было назначать клавиши на клавиатуре по своему, самому выбрать какие ноты.

Comment: В VMPK я вижу «Правка → Привязки клавиш»